# What does output of Erlang command : erl mean?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, erl

When I type erl at terminal , I get the following output:

[image: Output of Erlang command: erl]

I am just interested in each of the things which is shown in the output of erl command. For example:

1. What does 17 signify?
2. What does erts-6.2 signify? (Erlang Runtime System?)
3. What does smp:2:2 signify? (Symmetric Multiprocessors - 2 cores?)
4. What does async-threads:10 signify? (It has started some 10 threads in context of erl process?)
5. What does kernel-poll:false signify? (Not polling kernel for what?)
6. What does Eshell V6.2 signify? (I guess it means that shell version is 6.2)

I am just curious. Please help. Thanks.